# cannot connect to postfix on 587

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

I spent a lot of time searching for answers on related posts here, but to no avail. So that's why I am asking this question here.

- I have: Debian 8, Postfix, Dovecot
- I can send and receive emails with roundcube.
- I can receive emails with thunderbird.
- I cannot send emails with thunderbird.
- Thunderbird says it connects to the server, but it times out because there is no response from the server.
- I disabled my firewall.
- I am not sure what to fill out in the server
  name field.
- The emails I am trying to send end up in the concepts box on the server

I followed https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie

This is my current config.

```
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = server.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
myhostname = server.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_milters = local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/.ssl/mail_example_com_bundle.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/.ssl/mail_example_com.key
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
root@server:/etc/dovecot/conf.d# clear
root@server:/etc/dovecot/conf.d# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = server.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
myhostname = server.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_milters = local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/.ssl/mail_example_com_bundle.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/.ssl/mail_example_com.key
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

postconf | grep smtpd_sasl_auth_enable:

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

postconf | grep smtp_sasl_auth_enable:

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

when I connect using telnet to port 25 I get the following response from ehlo

```
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

AUTH is not enabled. Why?

When I try connect using telnet on 587 I see a blank screen.

I have no clue. Hope someone here does.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: look for error messages in /var/log/mail.log

Comment: that is a good suggestion. it got me this: fatal: invalid "-o smtp_sasl_auth_enable" option value: missing '=' after attribute name.. I got spaces there... this solved the issue indeed

Comment: I can successfully connect, but still not send. Relay access denied. So I guess something else needs tweeking as well. @cstamas Also still not getting AUTH in my telnet when I connect to 587.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell to postfix to listen to the submission port. Look in master.cf, usually under /etc/postfix, and uncomment the line:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

Also, check the firewall(s) settings to be sure the port 587 is reachable from your client.

Comment: That's right. I already have this in the master.cf: \n `submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject`

Comment: also for your reference I include the scan of ports: PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
110/tcp  open  pop3
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
465/tcp  open  smtps
587/tcp  open  submission
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Comment: I am having a new situation: I can now connect, but mails are not sent, most likely because of: `postfix/smtp[4793]: fatal: specify a password table via the 'smtp_sasl_password_maps' configuration parameter
`

Comment: finally I had to remove: `smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
` from the main.cf. It works fine now. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

For submission this is something you should have in `master.cf`

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
 -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
 -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

Answer (score 0):

@cstamas ' suggestion was a good one. I noticed having spaces around the = in `smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes` that should be  `smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes` then the first problem is solved.

after that I got an error 'Relay access denied', which was solved by adding:

```
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated
```

in the /etc/postfix/master.cf

Then I also had an error in the client configuration. I should use a server name that has a valid certificate installed, so the client can verify the servers identity.

Comment: also see my other answer below. There is a reason this is the debian default configuration file. e.g: it does enable authentication for the submission port only and ensures tls encryption.