# Postfix can receive but not send on port 587

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I have followed this guide to setup an email server: https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

I can send and receive fine, I also installed roundcube which allows me to send and receive email because it was setup to use the mail function to send email.

However, if for example I use the email client Geary, it allows me to receive email and check my inbox but sending over SMTP is totally not working, basically connection timed out and no logs show within mail.log for anything going on.

I have found this link: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23280159/Recipient-address-rejected-Relay-access-denied-How-do-I-fix-this.html

I feel from following that post above I have got it down to Postfix not having `cyrus-sasl` support setup? But that post was for a different OS than what I have.

I am on Debian 8, my question is do I need cyrus-sasl? I ran `postconf -a` and it just shows `cyrus` and `dovecot` no `cyrus-sasl` and I am not sure how to even install that.

I found [cannot connect to postfix on 587](https://serverfault.com/questions/795012/cannot-connect-to-postfix-on-587/795021) but have read through it and nothing seems to work? How come there is just no solid solution for this?

In the mean time I get these warnings when restarting postfix:

```
postfix[15180]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions
Jun  9 00:58:31  postfix[15180]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions
Jun  9 00:58:31  postfix[15180]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions
Jun  9 00:58:31  postfix[15180]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions
Jun  9 00:58:31  postfix[15180]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions
Jun  9 00:58:31  postfix[15180]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions
```

UPDATE:

main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

#Enable TLS/ SASL/ SSL
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.[my.domain].com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.[my.domain].com/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

#Enabling SMTP for authenticated users, and handing off authentication to Dovecot
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  permit_sasl_authenticated,  permit_mynetworks, check_relay_domains
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = Thunderbird-1
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#mydestination = Thunderbird-1, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

#Handing off local delivery to Dovecot's LMTP, and telling it where to store mail
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

#Virtual domains, users, and aliases
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,
        mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf
```

master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Comment: Please add your `main.cf` and `master.cf`.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Done...

Comment: @EsaJokinen Any idea mate?

Comment: You don't need cyrus-sasl, dovecot is doing that auth piece for you.  Maybe permission problems on the socket (wherever that private/auth path is) and track down those postfix/submission and postfix/smtps logfiles.  Something has to be telling you what's going on.  Might as well comment out those conf lines with $mua_XXX in them as well, that looks like something left over from a broken webmin install or something.

Comment: Please also have a look at your mail log (`/var/log/mail.log`) and post all liens related to a connection attempt.